# Magento Blog extension error

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, magento-ce

I'm using Trego theme on a brand new magento installation. This theme comes with a Blog extension for Magento that seems to not work. I'm pasting what the page throws to me when I click on the "Blog" link in the Home Page:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85967f18a3527096a513#file-blog_error

```
There has been an error processing your request
String could not be parsed as XML

Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/trego/template/trego_blog/flickrphotos.phtml(11): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('right', true)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/trego/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(26): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('right')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Trego/Blog/controllers/IndexController.php(28): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Trego_Blog_IndexController->listAction()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('list')
#19 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /var/www/vhosts/pipioletta.com/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Well, assuming that this is my second week with magento I am a bit lost and I really don't know how to proceed to solve this error.

Cheers.

Comment: Please have a look in the [great debugging tutorial](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party theme

Comment: Welcome, unfortunately questions about specific themes or modules are considered off-topic. Please feel free to post about specific Magento issues or questions you may have. Also there is insufficient information to even hazard a  guess as to what is wrong. Contact the developer of the theme directly for support.

Comment: No need to get close crazy — there's a Magento programming question hidden in there :)

Comment: This site is useless if the discussion cannot be extended to known modules. If this site does not have support for related topics then is totally useless. Drupal site has discussions and requests about stuff like Webforms, which is another 3rd party module. Dont see any reason at all to not do the same here. Opening a META now...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of the theme's `phtml` files

```
app/design/frontend/default/trego/template/trego_blog/flickrphotos.phtml
```

is trying to instantiate an empty Simple XML object — around line 11.  My guess is there's some sort of flickr integration that's fetching something the theme assumes will be XML, but isn't XML.  Maybe the theme has some flickr API credentials you're supposed to enter?  Have you checked the theme's documentation or reached out to its creator for support?

Without seeing the specific code in `flickrphotos.phtml` it's not likely people will be able to help out.